# Cant redirect using php's header function

Tags: php, redirect, header

I am having a very strange issue. I am doing bunch of redirects on a website and want to redirect '/old_url' and '/old_url.html' to '/new_url'.
Everyting works fine with '/old_url', however the '/old_url.html' always returns 404. After inspecticting the response header, I can see my redirect listed there, but it simply doesnt redirect.
Here is my code

```
 if($query && !headers_sent()){
        header('Location: ' . $query[0]['new_url'], true, (int)$query[0]['status_code']);
        exit;
 }
```

And here are the response headers from the browser.
[image]

As you can see there is a location header. Anyone knows why it is not working?

Comment: Guess: `(int)$query[0]['status_code']` is `404`…!?

Comment: If you want to use redirection, set HTTP status code to 3XX.

Comment: No, my status code is 302.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird..
This code is not working.

```
 header('Location: ' . $query[0]['new_url'], true, (int)$query[0]['status_code']);
 exit;
```

But this one works.

```
switch($query[0]['status_code']){
    case 301:
     header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
     header("Location: " . $query[0]['new_url']);
     exit;
    break;
    case 302:
      header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily"); 
      header("Location: " . $query[0]['new_url']);
      exit;
     break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a browser will not follow a Location header, if the HTTP status is 404. Send a 301 Status code with your response and you should be fine

Your response should look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: {URL}
```

Also i would recommend to send redirect to an absolute url

**UPDATE**

Have a look at this: http://php.net/http-response-code

Answer (score 0):

`/old_url`, is a path which will result in reading the `index.php / index.htm`.

`/old_url.html` is a file, which tries to read the file itself, not any PHP script.

You might want to use something like htaccess for redirecting.

Comment: That highly depends on your web server configuration now, don't it? Also not sure how that answers anything.

Comment: Depends on the configuration, yes. But it's default, so I would give it try. However, redirecting using htaccess might be the better solution anyway.

Comment: Just because something ends with .html doesnt make it a valid html file.